# mp3 play in IE - how to play in browser and not Window Media Player?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mp3, windows-media-player

I'm developing a website which has mp3 sound clips of wildlife. My client would like to be able to open multiple sound clips at any one time to create a chorus effect.
I've set the mp3 files to open in a new tab – it seems to work fine for all browsers apart from IE. IE opens the new tab, then automatically opens Windows Media Player to play the clip. Opening a second clip from the website overwrites the first one etc. On Chrome, Firefox etc, multiple tabs just open and play through the browser's media player. Is it possible to do this in IE?
Thanks!

Comment: It would kinda help a bit if you've shown at least some code of yours...

Comment: Which version of IE do you use? Maybe your IE was made when MP3 did not exist. BTW. I recommend to use OGG instead of MP3 on web, it is not protected by licence and supported by most of browsers.

Comment: @walther : Re the code - each link is as follows: <a href="link.mp3" target="_blank">Name</a>

Comment: @IvanKuckir - interesting you've said that! We've just checked. It works fine on IE9, but not IE9 64bit which we were using. I don't use IE because I'm on Mac so it's harder for me to check

Comment: You should try modern.ie where you can download free VM with Windows and Internet Explorer. Works with Mac.